# Deactivate Lightsail default key pair

Tags: key-pair, amazon-lightsail

How can I deactivate a lightsail default key pair for a specific region. The key was used to sftp onto the machine and I no longer want the default key to work, but replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot fully disable the default key.

You can, however, create a custom key and upload that to Lightsail. Then use that when you create future instances.

If you want do disable the default key on a currently running instance, simply add a new public key to that machine for new key pair, and remove the default one on that particular instance.

Comment: Someone actually got hold of the default key in that zone, so it basically means I can't use the default key for any instance on that zone? There really should be a way of refreshing that key/deleting it etc. in case it gets compromised for that zone.

Comment: Fair piece of feedback, I'll pass it along to the engineering team.

Comment: While there is no "button" to do this, if you open a case with AWS support they can reset your default key for you.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have that level of support and can only request limit increases through the basic support plan.

Comment: @MikeColeman The inability to delete/change the default key on Amazon Lightsail means that Amazon (employees or otherwise) have unrestricted access to server instances on Amazon Lightsail.

Comment: @philosopher i don't think this is true, because you can set a new key when creating an instance. I think you could create a new key per instance and would therefore achieve pretty good security. It is indeed a shame that the default key-pair can't be reset though, as it becomes useless once it has been downloaded to an insecure place